# Terminal-Browser with Flash

Tags: command-line, browser

I want to know if it's possible to enter a Flash site from the terminal. I'm playing a web-game based on Flash, so I want to make my server consume as low CPU as possible. I saw that I can do it, but didn't find one with Flash support. Does anyone knows one?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! As it stands, your question may need a little more information  in order for it to be answered. For example, what terminal browsers have you tried out already and what the results where. Also, it might be useful to know which website you are trying to reach.

Answer (score 3):

### Short and sweet: No.

A terminal is only capable of displaying text. Flash is far more advanced than just text. The terminal browsers out there display nothing more than the text of websites. It is simply not possible to embed Flash support on a terminal browser.

Comment: do you think there is a better way to low the CPU usage? using mozilla/iceweasel take too much CPU..

Comment: Nope.  Those browsers are both relatively low usage, actually. Especially compared to Chrome/Chromium. Your best bet would be to just not have *any* other applications open. Or, you can switch to a lighter desktop such as XFCE or LXDE.